# How do I resolve this warning about passing a function pointer to a macro in C?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, compiler-warnings

I have a macro defined as:

```
#define _call(func_name, __func_proto, ...)        {       \
 void *_handle;                                           \
 int result = !CERR_V_SUCCESS;                               \
                                                              \
  _handle = dlopen(_DLL_NAME,GLOBAL); \
  if (_handle) {                                           \
      __func_proto = dlsym(dll_handle, func_name);            \
      if (__func_proto) {                                     \
          result = (*__func_proto)(__VA_ARGS__);              \
     }                                                       \
      (void)dlclose(_handle);                              \
  }                                                           \
  return (result);                                            \
}
```

I am calling this macro with different function pointers like this:

```
_call("download",_download,src,dst);
_call("upload",_upload,src,dst);
_call("test",_test,file);
```

and the function pointers are defined as

```
int (*_download )(int *,int *);
int (*_upload)(int *,int*);
int (*_test)(int *,char*);
```

This results in a warning `a value of type "void *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "int (*)(int*,int*)"`.

How can I resolve this warning?

Comment: Is that your actual macro?

Comment: Yes i have defined this macro to load some dll ,i haven't added definition here but it has defination as well

Comment: Looks like cast is missing, but without the actual macro it's hard to tell

Comment: Please read on [mcve].

Comment: Yes it's a casting problem i guess ,not related with definition of macro

Comment: Is it possible to pass function pointers of different type in __func_proto parameter of macro?

Answer (score 3):

[Documentation of dlsym](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlsym.html) suggests you should cast the function pointer to `void*` before you assign its return value to the pointer:

```
*(void **)(&__func_proto) = dlsym(dll_handle, func_name);
```

Rationale is described behind the link:

> The ISO C standard does not require that pointers to functions can be cast back and forth to pointers to data. Indeed, the ISO C standard does not require that an object of type void * can hold a pointer to a function. Implementations supporting the XSI extension, however, do require that an object of type void * can hold a pointer to a function.
>
> Note that compilers conforming to the ISO C standard are required to generate a warning if a conversion from a void * pointer to a function pointer is attempted as in:
>
> fptr = (int (*)(int))dlsym(handle, "my_function");

Comment: Nitpicking: The snippet you show does not *cast* to `void*`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add casts, since `void *` doesn't convert to/from function pointers automatically. In fact it's non-portable to assume that function pointers can be expressed as `void *` at all.

Of course, if you're on a system that has `dlopen()` and friends, it can be a sure assumption that that platform supports this conversion.

Also, it sounds very strange to do the whole `dlopen()`/`dlsym()`/`dlclose()` dance *per call*, usually you buffer the pointers.